# Android HttpURLConnection getResponseCode() hangs after sleeping

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a thread that runs in a service that periodically sends updates to a server. As the user uses the app, it stores messages in the database and every minute, it queries the database and sends all the updates.

Everything works fine until I hit the lock button, leave the device for 10-15 minutes, then start using it again. It gets stuck at getResponseCode()

Here's what the thread looks like

```
 at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)   
  at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)  
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)    
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)    
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)    
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)   
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241) 
  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)  
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227) 
  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201) 
  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)   
  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)  
  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274) 
  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
```

The thread just hangs there indefinitely, never timing out.

Here's what the code looks like

```
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection( );

          connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
          connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
          connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length",
              Integer.toString( reqDataBytes.length ) );

          connection.setUseCaches( false );
          connection.setDoInput( true );
          connection.setDoOutput( true );

          connection.setConnectTimeout( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS );

          /* write request */
          DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream( ) );
          wr.write( reqDataBytes );
          wr.flush( );
          wr.close( );

          /* check for success */
          int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode( );
          if ( responseCode != 200 ) {
            connection.disconnect( );
            return null;
          }
...
```

I should also mention I'm using a wakelock and wifilock and calling

```
   MyApplication.getInstance( ).getWakeLock( ).acquire( );
    MyApplication.getInstance( ).getWifiLock( ).acquire( );
```

in onStartCommand() in my Service and releasing them in onDestroy() as well as setting the WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY to WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER in onCreate() in MyApplication

```
 Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY,android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!